# How to create a namespace in aerospike in Mac OS?

Tags: caching, vagrant, aerospike

I am new to aerospike and wanted to create a new namespace in aerospike.

How can this be achieved?

I have installed aerospike using vagrant and running aerospike using following commands:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by following steps:

1. Go to the vagrant VM

   ```
   vagrant up    
   vagrant ssh
   ```
2. Open the aerospike.cong file in etc/aersospike directory

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf
   ```
3. Add the new namespace in file as follows:

   ```
   namespace kvtest {
       replication-factor 2
       memory-size 1G
       default-ttl 5d # 5 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.


       # To use file storage backing, comment out the line above and use the
       # following lines instead.
       storage-engine device {
               file /opt/aerospike/data/catalog.dat
               filesize 5G
               data-in-memory true # Store data in memory in addition to file.
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, and I'd add: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac/index.html

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.